# ice:selectmenu throws an exception when accesing value in but it's displayed in ice:outputText

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

I've got an arraylist with a list of client objects that I populate in a ViewScoped bean and than pass to ui:repeat like:

```
ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedClients}" var="row"
```

one of my rows has ice:selectOneMenu as follows:

```
<ice:selectOneMenu id ="categories" required="true" value="#{row.newCategory}">
  <f:selectItems id="categoryItems" value="#{bean.categoryItems}"/>
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

client bean:

```
public final class Client {
  private String primaryId = null;
  private String name = null;
  private String newCategory = null;

.
.
.
}
```

Exception thrown when page is rendered:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/client.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:value="#{row.newCategory}": The class 'za.co.aforbes.fpc.ui.bean.table.DataTable$Row' does not have the property 'newCategory'
```

When I replace the dropdown with outputtext, the value is displayed

I don't understand this behaviour, please help

Comment: Does `#{bean.categoryItems}` resolve to something? Does it have `SelectItem` objects? Try to narrow down the problem since it works for one and not for the other.

Comment: @User49234123412341, thanks for you suggestion but it works now all of a sudden without any code changes. I did a maven clean build instead of the eclipse project clean. Must be some sort of cache problem or something - very weird. Thanks again